# Profiling agent failed to upload log snapshot to Microsoft Azure storage account

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, visual-studio

I publish Azure Web Role project with CPU profiler on. When I request Profiling Report, I get

```
19:04:43 - Connecting to the Profiling agent on the VM instance
19:04:44 - The Profiling agent is preparing to process the request
19:04:45 - Preparing the Profiling logs on the VM instance
19:05:00 - Uploading the logs from the VM instance to the Microsoft Azure storage account.
19:05:01 - Profiling log request failed. Details: Profiling agent failed to upload log snapshot to Microsoft Azure storage account
```

The storage account seems to be OK (I tried two). How to get rid of this error?